# How can I show the guessed letters of a word guesser in order? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been asked to create a word guesser in python which outputs to the user how many letters are in the word, for example python has 6, so it would output 6. Then the user has 5 guesses to guess what letters are in the word, after these 5 guesses, the user is meant to guess the word. I've been able to display what letters have been guessed correctly by concatenating them to a new string, but I've not been able to display the correct position of the word and also if the letter appears twice in the word, essentially like hangman.

Question 1: How can I get the letters guessed correctly to appear in the order of the word and not the order they are guessed in?

Question 2: How do I get a repeating letter to show however many times it appears in the word?

Code below:

```
#WordGuesser

import random

WORDS = ("computer","science","python","pascal","welcome")

word = random.choice(WORDS)
correctLetters = ""
guesses = 0

print(
    """

    Welcome to Word Guesser!
    You have 5 chances to ask if a certain letter is in the word
    After that, you must guess the word!

    """
)

print("The length of the word is", len(word))


while guesses != 5:
    letter = input("Guess a letter: ")

    if letter.lower() in word:
        print("Well done", letter, "is in the word")
        correctLetters += letter
        print("Correctly guessed letters are: ",correctLetters)
        guesses += 1


    else:
        print("No", letter, "is not in the word")
        correctLetters += "-"
        guesses += 1

guess = input("Please now guess a word that it could be!: ")

if guess == word:
    print("Well done, you guessed it")
    input("\n\nPress enter key to exit")

else:
    ("You did not guess it, the word was: ",word)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over the word instead in order output the guessed letters in the word of the letters in the correct word. Use a set instead to keep track of the correct letters for efficient lookups since you only need it to determine whether or not a letter has been correctly guessed:

```
correctLetters = set()
while guesses != 5:
    letter = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

    if letter in word:
        print("Well done", letter, "is in the word")
        correctLetters.add(letter)
        print("Correctly guessed letters are: ", ''.join(letter if letter in correctLetters else '-' for letter in word))

    else:
        print("No", letter, "is not in the word")
    guesses += 1
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/WellmadeAlarmingInformation

Comment: +1. you dont need to test membership when adding to the set though - looping through the word’s letters will ignore anything wrongly guessed.

Comment: Yes, but since there is already such a conditional statement for other purposes, might as well put the `add` call inside the condition to save it from needlessly keeping track of wrong letters that won't be needed when displaying the half-guessed word.

Comment: agreed.  except that putting it within the “guessed right” IF somewhat obscures the simplicity of the set-based approach.  mem size wont matter here and a set membership test is so quick.  but yes, you have your IF already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, not elegant as you can't use function, but it's work.

```py
import random

WORDS = ("computer","science","python","pascal","welcome")

word = random.choice(WORDS)
correctLetters = ""
guesses = 0

print(
    """

    Welcome to Word Guesser!
    You have 5 chances to ask if a certain letter is in the word
    After that, you must guess the word!

    """
)

print("The length of the word is", len(word))



while guesses != 5:
    list_word = list(word)
    letter = input("Guess a letter: ")

    if letter.lower() in word:
        print("Well done", letter, "is in the word")
        correctLetters += letter
        guess_part = ""
        for word_letter in list_word:
            if word_letter in correctLetters:
                guess_part += word_letter
            else:
                guess_part += "*"
        print("Correctly guessed letters are: ", guess_part)
        guesses += 1


    else:
        print("No", letter, "is not in the word")
        correctLetters += "-"
        guesses += 1

guess = input("Please now guess a word that it could be!: ")

if guess == word:
    print("Well done, you guessed it")
    input("\n\nPress enter key to exit")

else:
    ("You did not guess it, the word was: ",word)
```